# Indefinite article after as?

Tags: grammar, articles, uncountable-nouns

I read that when you classify or define people and things you use a/an:

*Don't use your plate as an ashtray.*

But then I found a news article which included the following sentence:

> Indian teenager allegedly raped twice after cops failed to follow her after using her as 'bait'.

Shouldn't the correct sentence be "using her as a bait?"

My question is as follows:

1. Which is grammatically correct? *Using her as bait* or *using her as a bait*?
2. If the former is correct then why is the indefinite article not used 
   after as? Isn't it defining her as a bait?
3. If both are grammatically correct then what is the difference in meaning or usage?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: *An* should be used before Indian, too.

Comment: But that's symptomatic of a newspaper headline, although that might indicate that the article has been omitted from *bait* for the same reason (which is not the case).

Comment: @AndrewLeach It doesn't look that concise for a headline.

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't; but [it is a headline](http://www.news.com.au/world/asia/indian-teenager-allegedly-raped-twice-after-cops-failed-to-follow-her-after-using-her-as-bait/story-fnh81fz8-1227441219929).

Comment: @AndrewLeach Apparently, the OP's "I found a news article which included the following sentence" is a bit misleading.Then, it can explain why "a" was not used before bait, too.

Answer (score 9):

The absence of articles at all in the sentence indicates that it's a [newspaper headline](http://www.news.com.au/world/asia/indian-teenager-allegedly-raped-twice-after-cops-failed-to-follow-her-after-using-her-as-bait/story-fnh81fz8-1227441219929), as such a practice is a common way of saving space. However, not every noun which is missing an article should actually have one.

*Bait* is a [mass noun](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bait) so it's uncountable and cannot usually take an article, in the same way as *furniture* doesn't.

> Indian teenager used as furniture
>   *Indian teenager used as a furniture

As with all such nouns, different **types** can be enumerated and in that case, an article may be appropriate.

> Wensleydale is a cheese beloved of plasticine Yorkshiremen and their dogs.

Note that the use of *as* is immaterial here; it's the noun itself and its properties as a mass/ non-count noun which determines whether an article is needed.

The *Indian teenager* should indeed have an article, because *teenager* is a count noun rather than a mass noun. But this has been omitted in the headline.

Comment: In the same dictionary, bait is used as a countable noun. [count noun]: ‘fishing with live baits’. Was it intentional to use BrE definition?

Comment: It is possible for non-count nouns to become countable when you are differentiating between variants: types of bait, cheese, or **maybe** even furniture. But *furnitures* would be far more unusual than *types of furniture.*

Comment: Absolutely. The bait in the context is *a* human bait. It is not like an earthworm or something that you use for fishing. That's why we need to differentiate it from a mass noun.

Comment: @Rathony I can't agree with you there I'm afraid. *...using her as bait* would seem far more natural.

Comment: @WS2  Believe me.  I know why you are saying that. I don't have to agree with you, right? Using an article is not a grammatical issue any more. It is a style issue and I firmly believe time will prove it.

Comment: Comments are not intended for discussion. Please write an answer if you disagree with this one, or vote on existing answers if you would rather do that. (Or, if you are making additional points in comments which can be edited into your own existing answer, do that too.)

Comment: Your answer at [“Seems like an overkill” vs. “seems like overkill”](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E2%80%9CSeems+like+an+overkill%E2%80%9D+vs.+%E2%80%9Cseems+like+overkill%E2%80%9D+) (closed as 'too basic') seems somewhat similar.

Comment: Surely, the mass noun is the only one appropriate in this context - *the police decided to use her as (a kind of) bait*.  It is tautologous to say *the police used her as a human bait* (because we know already that she ('her') is human).